# i want to use the strtolower function for my file types instead of putting them all in the extensions array, how can I do this?

Tags: php, html

I am confused as to how I can implement the `strtolower` function in my code, instead of having to include the uppercase file extensions in my extensions array.

I have tried to implement the following code, in many places, andI cant get it to work

```
$file_ext = strtolower(pathinfo($file_ext, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
```

```
    <?php 

      $phpFileUploadsErrors = array(
      0=> 'there is no error, the fle uploaded with success',
      1=> 'the file exceeds the upload max file size in php ini',
      2=> 'the file exceeds the upload max file size specified in HTML form',
      3=> 'uploaded file only partially uploaded',
      4=> 'no file was uploaded',
      5=> 'missing a temporary folder',
      6=> 'failed to write file to disk',
      7=> 'a php extension stopped the file upload',
      );

      function pre_r($array){
           echo '<pre>';
           print_r($array);
           echo '</pre>';
       }

      function reArrayFiles($file_post){
          $file_ary = array();
          $file_count = count($file_post['name']);
         $file_keys = array_keys($file_post);

          for($i=0; $i < $file_count; $i ++){
              foreach($file_keys as $key){
              $file_ary[$i][$key] = $file_post[$key][$i];
             }
       }
       return $file_ary;
      }
```

```
     <div>
     <form action="" method="POST" enctype ="multipart/form-data">
       <input type="file" name="userfile[]" value="" multiple="" >
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value ="upload">
     </form>
```

```
     <?php
     if(isset($_FILES['userfile'])){
       $file_array = reArrayFiles($_FILES['userfile']);
       pre_r($_FILES);
       for($i=0; $i<count($file_array); $i++){

         if($file_array[$i]['error']){
           ?> <div class = "alert alert-danger">
          <?php echo $file_array[$i]['name'].' - 
             '.$phpFileUploadsErrors[$file_array[$i]['error']];
          ?> </div> <?php
         }
         else{

          $extensions = array('jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'jpeg');

          $file_ext = explode('.', $file_array[$i]['name']);

          $file_ext = end($file_ext);
          echo $file_ext;

           if(!in_array($file_ext, $extensions)){
            ?> <div class = "alert alert-danger">
           <?php echo "{$file_array[$i]['name']} Invalid file extension!";
            ?> </div> <?php
          }
          else{
             move_uploaded_file($file_array[$i] 
             ['tmp_name'],"uploads/".$file_array[$i]['name']);
             ?> <div class = "alert alert-success">
             <?php echo $file_array[$i]['name'].' - 
              '.$phpFileUploadsErrors[$file_array[$i]['error']];
           ?> </div> <?php

          }
        }
      } 
    }    ?>
```

I am unsure how to implement it... I have included relevant code, including my functions...any help would be appreciated.. thank you

Comment: `if(!in_array(strtolower($file_ext), $extensions))`? What does the `echo $file_ext ` outputting? What about `var_dump($file_ext)`?